# Separate class for Qt app

Tags: qt

Under Fedora 27 Linux I want to try out a simple Hello World example with Qt and C++. I've created a separate GUI class which is populated with a label and a button. The init macro “Q_OBJECT” was commented out, because it produces an error message. ("undefined reference to vtable for MainWindow") After compiling the sourcecode, a window is shown on the screen, but the label and the button is missing. I mean, the compilation process works, the gui starts, but the result is not as expected.

If i put all the commands in the main-function without creating a separate class, Qt works great. The problem is to define a separate class which inherits from QMainWindow. Most of the example tutorials out there are working with Qt-Creator, but i want to do it from scratch on the command line level. Any hints are welcome.

```
// compile: clang++ -std=c++14 -lQtCore -lQtGui file.cpp
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QPushButton>
#include <QtGui/QTextEdit>
#include <QtGui/QLabel> 
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow> 
#include <iostream>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
  //Q_OBJECT
public:
  QWidget window;
  MainWindow() {
    window.resize(500, 400);
    QLabel label1( "input:" , &window);
    QPushButton button ("run", &window);
    button.move(0,300);
  }
  void show() {
    window.show();
  }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app (argc, argv);
  MainWindow mywindow;
  mywindow.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: """The init macro “Q_OBJECT” was commented out, because it produces an error message.""" - Which? This could be part of your general problem.

Comment: You need to run `moc` on your source files with class definition and include generated `moc_*.cpp` into your compile step. Btw, there are no errors in `Q_OBJECT` macro. Why you skipped an error description?

Comment: `QLabel label1` and `QPushButton button` are local variables in the constructor `MainWindow::MainWindow`. Hence, when constructor returns they are going out of scope and are destroyed/deleted. You have to make them member variables. (This is actually a C++ issue.)

Comment: Both your `QPushButton` and `QLabel` are scoped locally within the `MainWindow` constructor.

Comment: Additionally, I recommend to learn about Layouts e.g. in Qt doc.: [Basic Layouts Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QLabel label1` and `QPushButton button` are local variables in the constructor `MainWindow::MainWindow()`. Hence, when constructor returns they are going out of scope and are destroyed/deleted. You have to make them member variables. (This is actually a C++ issue.)

Additionally, I recommend to learn about layouting in Qt. Qt doc. provides examples e.g. [Basic Layouts Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwidgets-layouts-basiclayouts-example.html)

Here is an even smaller I composed by modifying the OP:

`testQMainWindow.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {
  private:
    QWidget central;
    QHBoxLayout hBox;
    QLabel label;
    QPushButton button;

  public:
    MainWindow();
};

MainWindow::MainWindow():
  hBox(this),
  label("input:", this),
  button("run", this)
{
  hBox.addWidget(&label, 1);
  hBox.addWidget(&button, 0);
  central.setLayout(&hBox);
  setCentralWidget(&central);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MainWindow win;
  win.show();
  return app.exec();
}
```

`testQMainWindow.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQMainWindow.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compile and test:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQMainWindow.pro

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQMainWindow.o testQMainWindow.cc
g++  -o testQMainWindow.exe testQMainWindow.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQMainWindow
```

[image: snapshot of ./testQMainWindow]

I'm working on Windows 10. I did the sample in [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org) which is the closest to Linux I have at hand.

Comment: You shouldn't need to link against `libGL`.

Comment: @Jaa-c Sorry, this was `qmake-qt5` which included `libGL`. ;-) If it's not used (i.e. not any symbol) it shouldn't hurt, should it?

Comment: @Jaa-c May be, `libGL` is probably a dependency which comes due to `QOpenGLWindow`/`QOpenGLWidget` etc. As you can see in the project file, I explicitly only required widgets: `QT += widgets`.

Answer (score 0):

> i want to do it from scratch on the command line level

In this case you either have to take care for all the necessary additional build steps, includes and linkage yourself, as Dmitry already hinted in a comment. Or you just use [`qmake`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html), which is highly recommended, because it takes care of all the Qt specific stuff.

Comment: Or CMake ;) latest version has great support of Qt.

Comment: This is only partial answer. His code is wrong, he creates his widgets on the stack in his constructor and never really adds them to his window. This should work even without qmake as he has no other resources and doesn't really need `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: @Jaa-c "This is only partial answer." Yes, it is. One problem after the other. "This should work even without qmake" Perhaps for that simple example, but more sooner than later things will grow more complex.